# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

My project in MVC 5.i wanted to handel **404**. i did it but problem is that

When I access the view using the following URL, everything works fine and as expected:

```
http://localhost/Hotels/Index30701000000
```

But when I access the view using following URL, I get 404.0 error message (error shown below)

```
http://localhost/Hotels/Edit/09099999dfdfb                       
http://localhost/Hotels/Edit/090/20130701000000
```

**Error: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

My code is

**Controller**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    // GET: Error
    public ActionResult Unauthorized()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        return View();
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig**

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Unauthorized",
        url: "Unauthorized/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Error",
            action = "Unauthorized",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );
```

**Global.asax**

```
    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
    }
```

**webconfig**

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Unauthorized" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
```

**View**  //Unauthorized.cshtml

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Unauthorized";
}
<h1>Page Not Found!</h1>
```

[Reference Link](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-handling-exceptions-and-404.html)

Comment: I don't know how to do that in `C#`, but why dont't you edit your server settings so it redirects every `404` to your custom page?

Comment: i don't know how do that,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> just Write these lines of code in global.asax file of your application.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        {
            if ((!Request.RawUrl.Contains("style")) && (!Request.RawUrl.Contains("images")))
            {
                Response.Clear();
                if (Response.StatusCode == 404)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("/ControllerName/ActionName");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach would be to define your error pages in an ErrorController, then use httpError section under system.WebServer in your web.config.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Error" />
</httpErrors>
```

The code above is so you can test your custom page. But in your development environment, you could replace Custom with errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" and existingResponse="Auto" so that you can still see the details errors.

I wrote a post about it recently, and it comes with a sample demo project available on GitHub you can play with. http://www.neptunecentury.com/Blogs/ASP-NET/MVC5/MVC-5-How-To-Show-Custom-Error-Pages